# How to disable ip6 lookups in unbound?

Tags: dns, ipv6, unbound

I attempted to disable IPv6 lookups in unbound through these options:

do-ip6: no

prefer-ip6: no

Really prefer-ip6 should only take effect when do-ip6 is yes.  In any case, I use tcpdump to dump the traffic and I still see IPv6 queries being issued to my forwarding server.

If I have disabled it, why is unbound still attempting to do IPv6?  Is there another hidden option that is silently enabling it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `do-ip6` setting stops unbound from sending or receiving DNS queries over IPv6. It does not stop unbound from talking about DNS IPv6 records over IPv4.

From the man page of `unbound.conf` (emphasis mine):

> do-ip6: (yes or no)
>
> Enable or disable whether ip6 queries are answered
>   or issued. Default is yes. If disabled, queries are not answered on 
>   IPv6, and  queries are not sent on IPv6 to the internet nameservers.
>   With this option you can disable the ipv6 transport for sending DNS
>   traffic, **it does not impact the contents of the DNS traffic, which
>   may have ip4 and ip6 addresses in it**.

Likewise, the `prefer-ip6` controls whether unbound prefers using IPv6 for talking to a DNS server that is reachable over both IPv4 and IPv6, or not.

To block reverse IPv6 queries, perhaps you could do something like this?

```
local-zone: ip6.arpa. refuse
```

Blocking forward queries about IPv6 addresses would require filtering out any queries about AAAA records. But a single query can include questions about several record types, and then the software would have to either strip away the IPv6-specific record types from the query, or to reject the entire query.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out all responses containing AAAA records as follows:

```
server:
   private-address: ::/0  # filters out all AAAA
```